# How can I get around casting to the FieldInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, json, system.reflection

How can i get around casting to FieldInfo? With the code below it throws InvalidCastException when derived class has i.e. bool variable. 
The problem is that it also returns null as a value of field. (everything happens in last 5 lines, but i paste more for context)

```
    {
        string paramsData = ".";
        if (param == null)
        {
            return paramsData;
        }
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public |
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                        BindingFlags.Instance |
                        BindingFlags.Static;
        FieldInfo[] paramFields = param.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);

        foreach (FieldInfo field in paramFields)
        {
            paramsData += field.Name;
            Param child = (Param)field.GetValue(param);
            paramsData += GetParamDataInChildren(child);
        }
        return paramsData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like you should be checking the type of your field before calling `GetValue`. For example:

```
if (field.FieldType == typeof(Param))
{
    Param child = (Param)field.GetValue(param);
    paramsData += GetParamDataInChildren(child);
}
```

Note that `child` could still be null in this case, and you should check for that if the subsequent function doesn't handle it.

[EDIT]
If you are trying to recursively get all the fields, regardless of type, you should make your recursive function take `Object` rather than `Param` and then you won't need to cast to `Param` as `GetValue` returns `Object`.